# Использование .loc для datetime with time zone

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime, index

Есть DataFrame:

```
                                   time  power
0      2019-12-12 22:00:00.425000+00:00  224.6
1      2019-12-12 22:00:01.409000+00:00  226.1
2      2019-12-12 22:00:02.428000+00:00  220.8
3      2019-12-12 22:00:03.408000+00:00  223.8
4      2019-12-12 22:00:04.409000+00:00  227.8
...                                 ...    ...
258378 2019-12-15 21:59:54.028000+00:00  230.5
258379 2019-12-15 21:59:55.050000+00:00  231.1
258380 2019-12-15 21:59:56.045000+00:00  230.9
258381 2019-12-15 21:59:57.068000+00:00  228.5
258382 2019-12-15 21:59:58.049000+00:00  228.5

#   Column  Non-Null Count   Dtype              
---  ------  --------------   -----              
 0   time    258383 non-null  datetime64[ns, UTC]
 1   power   258383 non-null  float64
```

Пытаюсь выполнить выборку на `2019-12-12`:

```
df1.loc['2019-12-12']
```

или

```
df1['time'].loc['2019-12-12']
```

Получаю:

> KeyError: '2019-12-12'

Подскажите, что делаю не так?

Comment: А что-нибудь типа df1['2019-12-12' < df1['time'] < '2019-12-13'] работает?

Comment: Просто через df1.loc вы ищете по индексу. Конечно, в индексе у вас таких значений нет.

Comment: Не работает :) Может надо time сделать индексом?

Comment: А что пишет? Мне помнится, Pandas вроде достаточно умным был и умеет даты сравнивать со строками... Или нет? %)  Попробуйте сделать индексом, тогда по крайней мере сможете использовать loc

Comment: смена индекса помогла. Но всё таки есть идеи как делать подобные выборки? df1['2019-12-12' < df1['time'] < '2019-12-13'] -  не работает.

Comment: @ЄвгенСкотаренко, чтобы поблагодарить авторов ответов можно [проголосовать за ответ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/173400/348814) и/или [принять ответ как правильный](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/348814)

Answer (score 4):

Пример:

```
In [27]: df.query("'2019-12-12 22:00:02+00:00' < time < '2019-12-13 00:00:00+00:00'")
Out[27]:
                              time  power
2 2019-12-12 22:00:02.428000+00:00  220.8
3 2019-12-12 22:00:03.408000+00:00  223.8
4 2019-12-12 22:00:04.409000+00:00  227.8
```

или так:

```
In [28]: df.loc[('2019-12-12 22:00:02+00:00' < df["time"]) & (df["time"] < '2019-12-13 00:00:00+00:00')]
Out[28]:
                              time  power
2 2019-12-12 22:00:02.428000+00:00  220.8
3 2019-12-12 22:00:03.408000+00:00  223.8
4 2019-12-12 22:00:04.409000+00:00  227.8
```

Answer (score 1):

```
df1.loc['2019-12-12']
```

Ваш индекс не состоит из значений дата-время типа `datetime64` в столбце `"time"`, но из значений `0, 1, 2, ..., 258382` типа `int64`. Потому нельзя использовать это значение в качестве `loc`.

Когда бы вы сделали из столбца `"time"` индекс, напримерь так:

```
df1.set_index("time", inplace=True)
```

то ваша команда `df1.loc['2019-12-12']` работала бы правильно.

---

```
df1['time'].loc['2019-12-12']
```

`df1['time']` - это серия, опять с индексом со значениями `0, 1, 2, ..., 258382` из вашего DataFrame `df1`. Значит - проблема та же самая.